# $\mathbb Q+X\mathbb R[X]$ is not Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A=\{q+r_1X+ \cdots +r_nX^n: q \in \mathbb{Q}, r_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the polynomial ring with rational costant terms. I have to prove that $A$ isn't a noetherian ring. How can I prove it?

Comment: Well, you can either use the definition of Noetherian ring, or some result you know of the form, "If $A$ is Noetherian, then (some statement about $A$)." What results do you know?

Comment: I know that there are three equivalent definitions:  ascending chain condition, every ideal is finitely generated and every non empty set of ideals has a maximal element.

Comment: You subject asks whether it is Noetherian, but you say you are asked to prove it is not. Which is it - are you asked whether $A$ Noetherian, or asked to prove it is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

consider the chain of ideals:

$\pi xA \subset \pi xA + \pi^2xA \subset\pi xA +\pi^2 xA +\pi^3 xA \subset ...$

Answer (score 6):

Let $R$ be an infinite set of reals which are linearly independent when the reals are considered a vector space over the rationals (such a set exists because the reals are uncountable and the rationals are countable). Then $\langle rx \, | r \in R \rangle$ will be an ideal that is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the ideal $I=\oplus _{i\geq 1}\mathbb R\cdot X^i\subset A$.
Despite appearances it is not equal to the ideal $(X)=XA$: we only have the inclusion $(X)\subsetneq I$ !
For example $\sqrt 2X\in I\setminus (X)$.
Once you understand this,  you will quickly be  able to see why $I$ is not finitely generated by considering the sequence $(r_jX)_j$ of polynomials in $I$, where the $r_j\in \mathbb R$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ .

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider ideals $I\subset x\mathbb R[x]$.